# Kicked off ssh server after changing sshd_config file

Tags: ssh, centos, authentication, sshd

My server only allowed passwordless root login via ssh. For example, ssh root@myserver.com would get me right in. I wanted to enable user login, e.g. ssh special_user@myserver.com would ask for a password.

I edited the sshd_config file by commenting out the line:

`AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`

to read:

`#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys`

and restarted the ssh server

`/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

I was immediately kicked off of the server, and now when I enter either root@myserver.com or special_user@myserver.com, I get this error:

`ssh: connect to host myserver.com port 22: Connection refused`

Is there any way to get ssh access back into my server, and potentially enable user logins?

Answer (score 0):

`Connection Refused` is a TCP level error meaning that there is no service bound to port 22. Simply put, `the ssh server is no longer running`.

Your best bet for recovery here is going to be a physical terminal, it seems as if you may have a corrupt *sshd_config* file, and the server failed to restart.